# Погода и ошибки, связанные с написанием кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

хочу написать код для погода, но сталкиваюсь с многими ошибками, которые никак не могу решить

```
#Импорт библиотеки
import pyowm

#Создание переменных
TOKEN = ('a5fcbb0425462f462a30e03e0024d121')
city = ("Москва")
observation = owm.get_weaather_at_place(city)
w = observation.get_weather()
temperature = w.get_temperature()

#Вывод
print("На данный момент, в городе Москва?: " + str(temperature) + "°C")
print("Так же в данном городе: " + w.get_detailed_status())
```

Вот сам код, что не так?

Выдаёт вот такую вот ошибку на данный момент при запуске

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Probing1.py", line 7, in <module>
    observation = owm.get_weaather_at_place(city)
NameError: name 'owm' is not defined
```

Так же есть вот такой вот код

```
#Импорт библиотеки
import pyowm

#Создание переменных
owm = pyowm.OWM('a5fcbb0425462f462a30e03e0024d121')
city = ("Москва")
observation = owm.get_weaather_at_place(city)
w = observation.get_weather()
temperature = w.get_temperature()

#Вывод
print("На данный момент, в городе Москва?: " + str(temperature) + "°C")
print("Так же в данном городе: " + w.get_detailed_status())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Probing1.py", line 7, in <module>
    observation = owm.get_weaather_at_place(city)
AttributeError: 'OWM' object has no attribute 'get_weaather_at_place'
```

Help

Comment: сначала почитать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=OWM

Comment: самое важное умение программиста - умение читать и понимать ошибки. Это даже важнее, чем само программирование.

Comment: еще одно важное умение - давать хорошие заголовки, отражающие суть проблемы, а не воду на киселе

Comment: Я уже читал сайт с pyowm и писал код, как было всё написано, но постоянно выдаёт ошибки

Comment: from pyowm import OWM

owm = OWM(151d78f45cca4317d79ea9438fe72a63)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

observation = mgr.weather_at_place('London,GB')
w = observation.weather
print(w)

Это всё такая же ошибка

  File "D:\Python\Probing1.py", line 3
    owm = OWM(151d78f45cca4317d79ea9438fe72a63)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: ```
from pyowm import OWM

owm = OWM(151d78f45cca4317d79ea9438fe72a63)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

observation = mgr.weather_at_place('London,GB')
w = observation.weather
print(w)
```

```
  File "D:\Python\Probing1.py", line 3
    owm = OWM(151d78f45cca4317d79ea9438fe72a63)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: токен, очевидно - строка... а у вас?

Comment: Так я только сгенерировал этот токен, что с ним не так?

Answer (score 1):

Поправил ваш код до рабочего, хотя пришлось всё методом тыка искать с помощью intellisence подсказок к объектам в `Google Colab`. Видимо, библиотека в текущей версии сильно отличается от той версии, по которой написано большинство кода в примерах в интернете.

```
#Импорт библиотеки
import pyowm

#Создание переменных
TOKEN = ('a5fcbb0425462f462a30e03e0024d121')
city = ("Москва")
owm = pyowm.OWM(TOKEN)
wm = owm.weather_manager()
observation = wm.weather_at_place(city)
w = observation.weather
temperature = w.temperature(unit='celsius')['temp']

#Вывод
print("На данный момент, в городе Москва: " + str(temperature) + "°C")
print("Так же в данном городе: " + w.detailed_status)
```

Вывод:

```
На данный момент, в городе Москва: 6.33°C
Так же в данном городе: clear sky
```